# C# Sum exclusion

Tags: c#

I have so far figured out how to do everything on this but I need to know how to make this code behave in this way.

```
*                   *
 *                 *
  *               *
   *             *
    *           *
     *         *
      *       *
       *     *
        *   *
         * *
          *
//and now the reverse


          *           
         * *
        *   *
       *     *
      *       *
     *         *
    *           *
   *             *
  *               *
 *                 *
*                   *
```

Whats the key too making it run back out like that? I assume starting at 5 and picking 2 integers but I I'm having a hard time tracking it. Here is what I have so far for the two previous solutions I was asked for.

```
//CIS 110 Program 7
//Online
using System;
class Program7
{
    static int count, sum, countmax;

    static void Main()
    {
        GetData();
    }
    static void GetData()
    {
        count = 0;
        sum = 0;
        countmax = 10;
        while (count <= countmax)
        {
            while (sum <= count)
            {
                sum++;
                Console.Write('*');
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            count++;
            sum = 0;
        }
    }
}
//*
//**
//***
//****
//*****
//******
//*******
//********
//*********
//**********
//***********
//Press any key to continue . . .

//CIS 110 Program 7
//Online
using System;
class Program7
{
    static int count, sum, countmax;

    static void Main()
    {
        GetData();
    }
    static void GetData()
    {
        count = 9;
        sum = 0;
        while (count >= 0)
        {
            while (sum <= count)
            {
                sum++;
                Console.Write('*');
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            count--;
            sum = 0;
        }

    }
}

//**********
//*********
//********
//*******
//******
//*****
//****
//***
//**
//*
//Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Why not just post the full question from your programming course?  I remember doing these introductory exercises 15 years ago at uni.  Alas, you already have people willingly doing your homework for you.

Answer (score 1):

In `C#`, you can use `PadLeft` to right-aligns the characters in this instance by padding them on the left.

```
static void GetData()
{
    int count = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int countmax = 15;
    bool IsOdd = countmax%2 ==1;

    // first half
    for(int i=1,j=0;i<=countmax/2;i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}","*".PadLeft(i), "*".PadLeft(countmax-i-(j++)));
    }       

    if(IsOdd) Console.WriteLine("*".PadLeft(countmax/2 +1)); // for odd count

    // Second half
    for(int i=IsOdd? countmax/2+1: countmax/2, j=0 ;i<countmax;i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}","*".PadLeft(i-(IsOdd?++j : j++)), "*".PadLeft(IsOdd?++j:j++));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
*     *
 *   *
  * *
   *
  * *
 *   *
*     *
```

Working [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hblVL7)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this by simple nested loops -

```
public static void Main()
        {
            GetData();
        }
        static void GetData()
        {
            int count = 11;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < count * 2; j++)
                {
                    var s = ((i + j == count) || (j - i == count)) ? "*" : " ";
                    Console.Write(s);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("------------Reverse------------");
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");

            for (int i = count; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                for (int j = count * 2; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    var s = ((i + j == count) || (j - i == count)) ? "*" : " ";
                    Console.Write(s);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: I have to make a nested loop for each one of those. How would I do that without reverse?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
var count = 7; // number of starts from centre star along one arm of the X

var range = Enumerable.Range(1, count);

var lines =
    range
        .Concat(range.Reverse().Skip(1))
        .Select(n =>
            "*".PadLeft(n, ' ')
            + (n == count ? "" : "*".PadLeft(2 * (count - n), ' ')));

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines));
```

That gives me:

```
*           *
 *         *
  *       *
   *     *
    *   *
     * *
      *
     * *
    *   *
   *     *
  *       *
 *         *
*           *
```